# Make cell blank if text found

Tags: excel

I'm new to excel . How to make cells which contain text is blank ? 
I tried to use If condition  like `=IF(A1=" ",  ,A1)` but didn't solve it

Comment: Use this formula -  =IF(ISTEXT(A1),"",A1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace a cell which contains text with blank, then use the below formula.

```
 =IF(ISTEXT(A1),"",A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not have a true blank cell as a result of a formula.

You need to put the blank, which is text, inside a pair of double quotes, or just return an empty string, which is simply an opening followed by a closing double quote character.

```
=IF(A1=" ","",A1)
```

Comment: well, what does the cell A1 really contain?